# sage maker using visual studio code locally instead of notebooks - SDK

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code, amazon-sagemaker

I prefer to use my local laptop for cost reasons + having an IDE like Visual Studio Code. As it stands my IT department is also not able/reluctant to setup database connectivity for could 9 etc. (so I would have to move data into S3 from local laptop). I also investigated [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/randomcutforest.html) to SSH into an EC2. However, again IT is unwilling to open up network connectivity ...

The issue I have is, that my laptop only has 8GB (windows). So from time to time I would like/have to use the cloud (e.g. to do hyperparameter optimisation etc.) and ultimately deploy models (e.g. as docker images R + plumber - Python + FASt API etc.). Coming across code like this (run in sagemaker notebooks):

```
estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    role=role_arn,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
    image_uri=container,
    debugger_hook_config=debugger_hook_config,
    rules=rules,
    sagemaker_session=session)
```

which is [SageMaker Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) code. Can I also execute everything locally via Visual Studio Code? I understand that SDKs like this are a constant moving target but can I use this and are there any books/tutorials (Google did not return much). Thanks.

Comment: On Google side take a look at TensorFlow cloud. https://github.com/tensorflow/cloud

Comment: @gogasca - thanks but I am interested in/tied to AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Use [SageMaker Local](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-amazon-sagemaker-local-mode-to-train-on-your-notebook-instance/) to execute training and inference locally in docker containers on your laptop.
In the Estimator, you'll specify: `instance_type='local'` or `instance_type='local_gpu'`

Comment: thanks this is good to know but would not really work in my situation as my laptop only has 8GB and I already struggle ...

Comment: I'm not what you're after. You can run the SageMaker SDK locally in your IDE, and relevant jobs will execute in the cloud.